# C++ - Printing prime numbers till N

Tags: c++, numbers, primes

**Question says:**

You are given an integer `N`. You need to print the series of all prime numbers till `N`.

I want to know what's wrong with my code and suggestions will also be of great help.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int  main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;  
    int u;

    for(int i = N; i > 0; i--)
    {
        u = 0;
        for(int j = 2; j < N-1; j++)
        {

            if(i % j == 0)
            {
                u = 1;     
            }
        }
        if(u == 0)
        {
            cout << i << " ";
        } 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that something is wrong with your code?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to look up the Sieve of Eratosthenes. For the specific case you're dealing with (finding all primes up to some limit) it's generally quite a bit faster than doing trial division.

Comment: I don't know, what do you think is wrong with it? I mean it appears to work (I haven't tested it) but it could be more efficient, it could be better indented, it could be better written. Be a bit more specific in what you are asking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First for future reference you should probably post that on code review, unless there is a specific problem then you should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

There is nothing inherently wrong other than you do not check that N>0 which could lead to an infinite loop, j should be going to i not N, and I think this would print 1 as a prime number which it is not. Here are some pointers:

1. Why are you going from N to 0? That seems a little counter intuitive compared from going from 2 to N (you can skip 1 since it is not prime)
2. If you are going to use a flag (`u`) then you should make it a `bool` which forces it to be either true or false
3. You do not need to do a flag, instead as soon as you find a divisor print the number and then break the inner loop like

   ```
   for(j=2; j< N-1; j++){
      if(i%j==0){
        cout << i << " ";
        break;
       }
    }
   ```
4. You do not need to have j go all the way to i, just the sqrt(i) since anything greater then the sqrt(i) that divides i must must be multiplied by some number smaller then the sqrt(i). So if i is not prime, then there must be a divisor below sqrt(i)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. These are definitely   some very good tips. I am new to this site so some tips on how to ask question more precise and accurately would help ! Thanks once again.